# Получение полного пути к любой dll библиотеке

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Разрабатываю приложение, выводящее различную информацию о процессах в системе. Одна из задач - вывести список используемых процессом dll библиотек и полных путей к ним. С именами библиотек проблем не возникло, но вот с получением путей косяки. 
Пытался использовать GetModuleFileName в паре с GetModuleHandleEx, но постоянно на всем списке модулей получаю путь к запущенному исполняемому файлу.

Код:

```
bool process::GenerateProcessDllList()

{
dll_list.clear();

MODULEENTRY32 moduleInfo;
moduleInfo.dwSize = sizeof(moduleInfo);

HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, this->PID);

if (processesSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

{

    for (BOOL bok = Module32First(processesSnapshot, &moduleInfo); bok; bok = Module32Next(processesSnapshot, &moduleInfo))

    {
        std::wstring temp(moduleInfo.szModule);

        TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
        HMODULE hm = NULL;

        if (GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, moduleInfo.szModule, &hm))

        {
            GetModuleFileName(hm, path, sizeof(path));
            std::wcout << path << std::endl;
        }

        if (IsUsingAslr(moduleInfo.szModule)) { temp += L" - [ASLR]"; }

        else { temp += L" - [NO ASLR]"; }

        this->dll_list.push_back(temp);

    }

    CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
    return true;

}

else { return false; }

}
```

Comment: Воспользовался функцией GetModuleHandle вместо GetModuleHandleEx, получил необходимое поведение. Почему - не понимаю, но вопрос можно закрыть.

Comment: "вопрос можно закрыть" - ответьте сами себе с зеленой галкой, тогда "закроется".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользовался функцией GetModuleHandle вместо GetModuleHandleEx, получил необходимое поведение.